# Geometry problem, triangle, angles, exercise from 2022 local competition

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Problem:**
Consider the triangle $ABC$, $\angle A = \angle B = 40^\circ$. The point $D$ on $AC$ is such that $\angle ABD=10^\circ$. Consider the point $E$ on $AB$ such that $BC=EB$.
Prove that $DE \parallel BC$.

**Context:** This is the reformulation (the conclusion is simplified) of an exercise from 2022 local competition. The official solution has -- in my opinion -- a big gap. They say:

Let $A'$ be symmetric to $A$ wrt $CE$. Then $AA'C$ is equilateral. From the sum of measures of angles in the triangle $AA'D$ we get that  $\angle ADA'=100^\circ$. Then $DE \parallel BC$. $\square$

The problem is that they took for granted that $E$ lies on $A'D$. This is equivalent to the conclusion and I don't understand how considering $A'$ can help.

My tries: Conclusion $\iff \angle AED = 40^\circ\iff \angle EDA = 100^\circ \iff AD=ED \iff E\in A'D$.

[image]

Comment: To verify that you made a faithful reproduction, can you post the entire problem/solution? Even a screenshot would be helpful.  $\quad$ It's not immediately clear to me how simple calculations show $ \angle ADA' = 100^\circ$ (without already assuming $DEA'$ is a straight line), so my guess is that they had to have done that already somewhere. Maybe that's what you meant by "the problem is that ..."?

Comment: @CalvinLin $\angle CAE = \angle CA'E = \angle CA'D$ where the last equality holds if $E$ lies on $A'D$. That, combined with $ACA' = 60^\circ$, gives the required result.

Comment: @DS Right, my point is that we had to assume E lies on A'D for a simple calculation.  I'm trying to figure out if that's what OP meant (hence the further clarifications to my comment), and if so it would have been better to show that directly (hence the request for the original solution).

Comment: This is equivalent to proving the reflection of $D$ lies on $AB$ (the point where the dotted line meets the blue one)

Comment: @DS $\angle DBA = 10^{\circ}$

Comment: @ShahainRDM oh, sorry, it was a typo. Mateo, I meant to say that you have not used the fact that $\angle DBA = 10^\circ$

Comment: @CalvinLin The conclusion was to prove that the area of triangles BEK and CKD are equal, where $\{K\} = BD\cap EC$. You're right. They assumed it in the whole proof.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I've changed my question to add a sentence: From the sum of measures of angles... This is precisely what they wrote.

Comment: @DS, you're right. In the original proof they didn't use it. The colinearity of $A'$, $E$ and $D$ magically happens for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be the intersection of $CA'$ and $AB$.
The goal is to show that $DC = CF$.
From there, $F$ is the reflection of $D$ along $CE$ and  $AEF$ is a straight line implies that it's reflection $A'ED$ is also a straight line (which is what OP wanted to show).

Let $BC = 1$.
Apply sine rule in triangle $BCD$: $DC / \sin 30^\circ = BC / \sin 50^\circ$, so $ DC = \frac{1}{2 \sin 50^\circ}$.
Apply sine rule in triangle $BCF$: $CF/ \sin 40^\circ = BC / \sin 100^\circ$, so  $CF = \frac{ \sin 40^\circ } { \sin 100^\circ}$.
Since $ \frac{\sin 40 ^\circ} { \sin 100^\circ} = \frac{ \sin 40 ^\circ } { 2 \sin 50^\circ \cos 50^\circ } = \frac{ 1 } { 2 \sin 50 ^\circ}$, so $DC = CF$ as desired.

Notes

- If we used this route, we didn't really need to use $A'$ to complete the original problem.

  - We have $FE = DE = DA$, which gives us that $DEA$ is isosceles and similar to $CBA$, so $ DE \parallel  CB$.

Comment: How did you calculate that  $\angle CFB = 100^{\circ}$? Assuming that you used $\triangle CFB$ for your second sine rule calculation.

Comment: @ShahainRDM $\angle A'C E = \angle ACE = 30 ^\circ$. So $\angle A'CB = 40^\circ$ and thus $\angle CFB = 100^\circ$. (I was looking out for 40-40-100 triangles)

Comment: Ok, then by virtue of symmetry it follows that $DC = CF$ anyways and then $\angle DEC = 70^{\circ}$ and without any hassle it simply follows that $\angle DEA = 40^{\circ}$ as desired.

Comment: @ShahainRDM That is to complete the solution that OP posted? If so, I added how we can do so via another way in the notes. $\quad$  I'm focusing only on showing that $A'ED$ is a straight line (which is what OP asked for), instead of showing the "some simple calculations implies $DE \parallel BC$".

Comment: @CalvinLin, thank you for the answer. I didn't find a solution, since I tried very hard to reproduce their proof, without using trigonometry, but instead using some 'clever movement', like searching for equilateral triangles, some rotation, reflection, extension of a segment, searching for four points on a circle and so on.